# Form inside JQuery menu

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form which has two hidden parameters that I want to pass to the function LoadView

```
<form name="frm1" action="http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/AddProduct/LoadView">
<input type="text" name="ID"  value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" hidden="true" >
<input type="text" name="Name"  value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" hidden="true">
<button id="add_product_button">Add product</button>
</form>
```

If I use a simple button everything works fine. What I want to do is to create a Jquery menu:

**Html:**

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>View All Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>Add New Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>View Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>Edit Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#menu" ).menu();

});
```

[image]

and the form be submitted when the user click on one Add New Product on this Jquery Menu. I tried to put the form inside an li tag but it didn't work. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form.submit()` to trigger form submission manually through jQuery.

**Documentation on .submit():**

```
Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
```

Therefore, simply attach a `.click()` event on the anchor wrapping the 'Add product' menu item and trigger the `.submit()` event.

**Your Solution:**

**Menu HTML Code:**

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>View All Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="addNewProduct"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>Add New Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>View Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>Edit Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Form HTML Code**

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/AddProduct/LoadView">
<input type="text" name="ID"  value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" hidden="true" >
<input type="text" name="Name"  value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" hidden="true">
<button id="add_product_button">Add product</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery Code:**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$( "#menu" ).menu();
$("#addNewProduct").click(function(){
   $("#frm1").submit();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>View All Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/AddProduct/LoadView?ID="<?=$ID?>&Name="<?=$Name?>"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></span>Add New Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>View Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomout"></span>Edit Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// give an id attribute to form tag
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" action="http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/AddProduct/LoadView">
<input type="text" name="ID"  value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" hidden="true" >
<input type="text" name="Name"  value="<?php echo $Name; ?>" hidden="true">
<button id="add_product_button">Add product</button>
</form>

Now on the click event of <li>add new product</li> do $('#frm1').submit();
```